# Including Delphi Type Libraries in repository (SVN)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, typelib, com-hell

What is the best way to save a Delphi Type Library in SVN.

The file changes every time you compile the Application

The file is not saved in a readable form of  AscII

It is very difficult to work out what changes have been made from one version to the next

**This is a  major problem when more than one person is changing the file**

**QUESTIONS:**

1) Should one save an exported ‘IDL’ file in the version control ?

2) Can one covert an ‘IDL ’ into a Delphi type library If so how ?

3) What are the best practices when working with a Delphi type library ?

4) How easy is it get rid of the type library in Delphi2009 datasnap project?

p.s. I am using BDS2006

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to Delphi 2009, I would not check in the TLB file but manually put the TLB (and  *_TLB.PAS file for reference) into a zip file then force that into version control.  When ever I made actual changes to the TLB, I would update the zip file and check it in.  The local TLB was always made read/write and ignored by the version control system.  This scheme saved me several times when the TLB file would mysteriously no longer compile, I could just close my project, unzip from the zip file, reload the project and continue working.

Answer (score 7):

In Delphi 2009, this has changed completely. [Type libraries are now saved in the project as plain text, RIDL files](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2008/07/tiburn-sneak-peek-com_23.html). These will play nice with source control. DataSnap is also completely changed; you can [read about it here](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/new_datasnap_tiburon.html), and see [a screencast](http://dn.codegear.com/article/38587) here.

Answer (score 4):

There are some good answers to this question at [Delphi and COM: TLB and maintenance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897/delphi-and-com-tlb-and-maintenance-issues).