# Delphi TLB editor replacement

Tags: delphi, typelib

Do you know any good TLB editor (even commercial) that can be used instead of the one which comes with Delphi? It gives headaches in a lot of situations (big TLB, rename an entry ... etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Delphi 7 for work but I have access to D2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We opted for an IDL -> (midl) -> TLB -> (tlibimp) _TLB.Pas workflow. Manually updating an IDL file is a good bit different from visually editing a TLB file, but as programmers we prefer to type out our interfaces anyway.

This workflow is from the pre-RIDL era, so we might update in the near future.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Now the only problem is that I have a prepared TLB, can I generate IDL from it? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: OleView (part of the Win32 sdk) can load a .tlb file, and exports to .idl.

Answer (score 4):

As I already mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446379/) the Type Library support is really really buggy, especially in Delphi 2005 - 2007.

In Delphi 2009 and 2010 it got better, although there are still many bugs (try to rename a class). BUT since Delphi 2009 the editor uses the [*RIDL* text format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/RIDL_File) instead of a binary format and so you can (and often have to) *manually* edit the TLB when the editor did something stupid.

**To answer your question:** No, it doesn't make sense to replace the editor, because you would loose all the automatic *RIDL to Delphi code* conversions.

Comment: Is there a Quality Central report for the Rename a Class in the RIDL Editor problems?

Answer (score 2):

The TLB editor from Delphi really sucked, but it got a major overhaul in Delphi 2009.

If updating to a newer version is an option, you can try to migrate to Delphi 2010 and see, if that solves your problems.

Comment: Delphi 2010 is fabulous.  Unfortunately above, someone reports that the RIDL editor still has some bugs, even in Delphi 2010.