# Com interop: Why tlibimp.exe generates read only properties?

Tags: c++, delphi, com

I've created a COM object with Visual Studio that I want to use with Delphi.

```cs
[Guid("9D0CCD2D-75E9-46AC-BC40-C4D84669FC45")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IMyComClassDispatch
{
    string PropertyString { get; set; }
    string funcGetString();
    void funcSetString(string aString);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyComClassDispatch : IMyComClassDispatch
{
    public string PropertyString { get; set; }


    public string varString;

    public string funcGetString()
    {
        return varString;
    }

    public void funcSetString(string aString)
    {
        varString = aString;
    }
}
```

Then I've generated the tlb file, and finally a pascal file corresponding to my COM object with tlibimp.exe bundled with Delphi 5:

```
C:\>tlibimp.exe -P+ mylib.tlb
```

and here is the generated code:

```
// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IMyComClassDispatch
// Flags:     (4096) Dispatchable
// GUID:      {9D0CCD2D-75E9-46AC-BC40-C4D84669FC45}
// *********************************************************************//
  IMyComClassDispatch = dispinterface
    ['{9D0CCD2D-75E9-46AC-BC40-C4D84669FC45}']
    property PropertyString: WideString readonly dispid 1610743808;
    function  funcGetString: WideString; dispid 1610743810;
    procedure funcSetString(const aString: WideString); dispid 1610743811;
  end;
```

The problem is that my property is marked as read only and I don't really see why that is happening, because this tool can also generates C++ code and the property can be modified:

```cpp
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface   : IMyComClassDispatch
// Indicateurs : (4096) Dispatchable
// GUID        : {9D0CCD2D-75E9-46AC-BC40-C4D84669FC45}
// *********************************************************************//
interface IMyComClassDispatch : public TDispWrapper<IDispatch>
{
  BSTR __fastcall get_PropertyString()
  {
    _TDispID _dispid(/* PropertyString */ DISPID(DISPID_UNKNOWN/*[1610743808]*/));
    TAutoArgs<0> _args;
    OlePropertyGet(_dispid, _args);
    return _args.GetRetVariant();
  }

  void __fastcall set_PropertyString(BSTR Param1/*[in]*/)
  {
    _TDispID _dispid(/* PropertyString */ DISPID(1610743808));
    TAutoArgs<1> _args;
    _args[1] = Param1 /*[VT_BSTR:0]*/;
    OlePropertyPut(_dispid, _args);
  }

  BSTR __fastcall funcGetString()
  {
    _TDispID _dispid(/* funcGetString */ DISPID(DISPID_UNKNOWN/*[1610743810]*/));
    TAutoArgs<0> _args;
    OleFunction(_dispid, _args);
    return _args.GetRetVariant();
  }

  void __fastcall funcSetString(BSTR aString/*[in]*/)
  {
    _TDispID _dispid(/* funcSetString */ DISPID(DISPID_UNKNOWN/*[1610743811]*/));
    TAutoArgs<1> _args;
    _args[1] = aString /*[VT_BSTR:0]*/;
    OleProcedure(_dispid, _args);
  }


  __property   BSTR            PropertyString = {read = get_PropertyString, write = set_PropertyString};
};
```

Does this means that I should avoid properties with COM objects or is there any options that I should change ? Is this a problem with tlibimp or a limitation of the compiler that cannot generate instructions to write on COM objects properties ?

Any help would be appreciated on this!

Comment: Maybe [`the right time`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16897/960757) for upgrade ?

Comment: Actually I hoped that I could upgrade smoothly to .NET using COM Interop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known defect in Delphi 5 & 6 tlibimp.exe. You shall upgrade to Delphi 7 or newer version to avoid it.

Comment: Do you have any source to prove what you are saying ? I'm almost sure that it comes from this old version but nothing giving any workarounds...

Comment: @EliasPlatek I encountered same problem years ago. No workarounds were found except manually (or by some script) editing generated file which is of course is not acceptable solution for industrial process. See e.g. discussion here: http://www.managed-vcl.com/phpBB3_2/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9

Comment: Thanks for the link! Actually I only need a newer version of tlibimp.exe right? Or do every versions are faulty ?

Comment: @EliasPlatek You could try to use `tlibimp` from Delphi 7, but I'm affraid newer version of `tlibimp` will generate code that will not compile under older versions of Delphi. As I remember we checked several workarounds for this, but finally moved to Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0):

Tlibimp.exe is bugged in Delphi 5, and there is no more support from Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero...

A workaround would be removing the readonly marker on the generated pas file. But in order to be sure that the code is correctly called, I made some modifications to prove that it works:

- In the COM object class, write in a file in the setter:

  ```
  public string PropertyString
  {
      get { return varString; }
      set
      {
          varString = value;
          File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\elias\Documents\com.txt", varString);
      }
  }
  ```
- Remove the readonly marker on properties in the .pas file generated from tlibimp.exe:

  ```
  // *********************************************************************//
  // DispIntf:  IMyComClassDispatch
  // Flags:     (4096) Dispatchable
  // GUID:      {9D0CCD2D-75E9-46AC-BC40-C4D84669FC45}
  // *********************************************************************//
    IMyComClassDispatch = dispinterface
      ['{9D0CCD2D-75E9-46AC-BC40-C4D84669FC45}']
      property PropertyString: WideString dispid 1610743808;
      function  funcGetString: WideString; dispid 1610743810;
      procedure funcSetString(const chaine: WideString); dispid 1610743811;
    end;
  ```
- Then you can use your COM object:

  ```
  var
    MyClass: IMyComClassDispatch;
  begin
    try
      MyClass:= CoMyComClassDispatch.Create;
      MyClass.PropertyString:= 'some value';
    finally
      MyClass._Release;
    end;
  end;
  ```

And the file is correctly written!

Now it's the only problem I have encountered in my project, I hope I won't have any other problems later...